# How to randomly distribute an attribute over a certain number of objects?

Tags: c++, object, random, boolean, distribution

I was wondering what's the best way to distribute something over a set number of objects. I'm trying to create a minesweeper game where there are a certain number of tiles, and a set number of mines, but I'm not sure the best way to randomly distribute numbers over a range.

Concretely, if I had a vector of say 400 objects, what's the best way to randomly distribute one boolean attribute so that like 30 of those 400 had true and the rest were false?

```
struct Tile {
  bool mine;
  // ...
};

std::vector<Tile> v(400);
```

---

I was thinking perhaps something like a probability system where a set number of my tiles absolutely had to have the attribute, and I could create a numbering vector of all the  objects and roll random numbers, then removing those objects from the vector until the met number of mines were set.

Comment: You could create an array of 400 bools, set the first 30 to true and the rest to false, shuffle the array, and use the shuffled values in order.

Comment: I've added a bit of code to make it clearer what you're asking. Feel free to edit it f you feel this changes the intent, or if you can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the array with the set amount of each values you want and then shuffle them.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Answer (score 0):

```
int N = 400;
int numMines = 30;
vector<bool> hasMine;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
   if(i < numMines) hasMine.push_back(true);
   else hasMine.push_back(false);
}  
random_shuffle(hasMine.begin(), hasMine.end());
```

If you care too much about the accuracy of your shuffle, you can use the shuffle method with a separate random generator(read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-vs-random_shuffle-c/)). But this should be good enough for a simple game.

Comment: `random_shuffle` has been removed in C++17, so you have to use `shuffle` now.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here is transform a randomly sampled subset of the vector. The [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library has `views::sample` that can be used for this purpose:

```
for (auto & tile : v | ranges::views::sample(30))
    tile.mine = true;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zY8dj4hc9).

This solution has the advantage that no copies of the vector need to be made, nor is any additional memory needed. Also, this works without moving around any of the objects in the vector.

This view is slated to be added to C++23, though it is only [Tier 3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html#tier-3) priority.